# How to get user input in JavaScript without prompt

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to get user input in JS without using the prompt(); command. I'm well aware that this question has been asked before, but all the other ones I could find included using html, whereas I'm looking for a way to do it in pure JavaScript, in a program, not as part of a webpage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then what technology are you using with Javascript if html is not available? Please share that point.

Comment: JS has no user interface capabilities, other than what's provided by the browser.

Comment: Node has non-html user input facilities. See https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/

Comment: There is no uniform way of getting user input built into the JavaScript language. The answer will vary depending on the runtime system. Are you using Node, for example?

Comment: @jorgonor It's not that it's not available, I'm just trying to only use javascript

Comment: @Saiid and the answer is "you can't - it depends on the technology you use"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has no native means of getting input. Every method that exists is an extension provided by the host environment (`prompt` is an example of that)

Different host environments have different methods. You've identified one for browsers, DOM is another. NodeJS has the Readline API (among others). There are lots of other environments (WSH, JXA, etc, etc).

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a specific command to get it out in the prompt but maybe you can use the alert();

Comment: `alert()` (a) is an API provided by implementations found in browsers (so doesn't really meet the "pure JavaScript" requirement of the question) and (b) only allows you to supply **output**, there is no use to get user input from it.

Answer (score 0):

JS has no "abilities" other than what is supplied by the browser. It is meant for use on a browser, unless you want to use Java, but that is a different story. So prompt would probably be the best way to go using JS, unless you want to use confirm, which would give you the equivalent of a Boolean expression.

```
var answer = confirm("Yes or no?")
```

This would give you a true or false answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to get user input in javascript if you are practicing/appearing for any competitive coding.

```
Input:
4
1 2 3 4
Output:
{
  n:4,
  arr:[1,2,3,4]
}
```

```
function runProgram(input){
    let line=input.split('\n')
    let n= Number(line[0]);
    let arr = line[1].split(' ').map(x => +x);
    yourFunc(n,arr);
}

function yourFunc(n,arr){
    console.log({n,arr})
}

if(process.env.USER === ""){
    runProgram('')
}
else{
    process.stdin.resume();
    process.stdin.setEncoding('ascii');
    let read="";
    process.stdin.on('data',function(inp){
        read+=inp
    })
    process.stdin.on('end',function(inp){
        read=read.replace(/\n$/,"");
        read=read.replace(/\n$/,"");
        runProgram(read);
    });
    process.on("SIGINT",function(){
        read=read.replace(/\n$/,"");
        runProgram(read);
        process.exit(0);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to grab the input without prompt., This method is very much useful for those who are using JS for competitive programming., by using nodeJS
we can write the function like this,

```
// rl means readline .. we have to require the readline through npm.

rl.question("Your favorite food? ", function(input) {
  console.log(input);
  rl.close();
});

// OUTPUT:- your favorite food? 
//          Pasta
```

Comment: Perhaps add that this is only possible in node, not the browser.